# The Birch-Swinerton-Dyer conjecture for rank 1

Tags: reference-request, birch-swinnerton-dyer

I'm reading the kolinvagin's work about the Birch Swinnerton-Dyer of elliptic curves woose rational points have rank one. I want to ask about the prerequisites to understand the Kolinvagin's work on Euler Systems.

Comment: The list of books and articles to give as reference to cover all these topics would be rather long - and it will depend on the level of how much you already understand. Maybe the list at http://math.harvard.edu/~yihang/GZSeminar.html will help.